# What happens when you cast to smaller integer?

Tags: go

Let's say you have an `int64` value. What happens if you cast that value to an `int32`. How does it affect the sign of the value? Is it equivalent to using a modulus operator?

Comment: What happened when you tried it with different numbers?

Comment: Go doesn't let you cast at all. But if you convert, you may overflow.

Comment: This is all explained in the language spec which is astonishingly compact and easy to understand. Just look it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are referring to a conversion, not a cast.  The relevant part of the [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) says:

> When converting between integer types, if the value is a signed integer, it is sign extended to implicit infinite precision; otherwise it is zero extended. It is then truncated to fit in the result type's size. For example, if v := uint16(0x10F0), then uint32(int8(v)) == 0xFFFFFFF0. The conversion always yields a valid value; there is no indication of overflow.

A conversion from `int64` to `int32` truncates. Truncation can affect the sign of the value.

A conversion from `int32` to `int64` retains the sign because of implicit sign extension.